# Is there a way to view google colab output in a public link like a video stream?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Is there a way to view google colab output in a public link like a video stream, I don't want the viewers to interact with it but just to view the output Thank You!

Comment: Depending on what you're outputting, there are many possible solutions. If it's just text, you could have a public webpage that the collab outputs to, and refreshes in realtime with the output. If you want image and sound output, you'd probably have to use some kind of streaming service's API, and generate images and sounds on the fly and encode them into a video stream. I think this question is pretty broad for StackOverflow though, I'd recommend a more generic software questions site like https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ possibly.

Comment: @RandomDavis streaming service's API?? Can i know more about it that's what i need

Comment: That's up to you to research, but I did find this: https://pypi.org/project/python-twitch-stream/